# Handlebars : register helper based on template with 'body content'

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to implement some kind of 'macro' mechanism in a nodejs application using Handlebars (similar to the @bodyContent system in velocity.)

In my main template, I want to be able to write something like this :

```
 {{#foobar who = user }}
    <p>My body content</p>
 {{/foobar}}
```

In a "views/helpers/foobar.html", I would have a file with a template, and some way to reference the "body content"

```
<p>Hello {{ who }}<p>
{{ bodyContent }}
<p>Bye !</p>
```

Based on the convention that the templates in "views/helpers" corresponds to a helper called with a single hash parameter, I want to automatically register them ; so I have something like this :

```
var helpers = "./views/helpers/";

fs.readdirSync(helpers).forEach(function (file) {

    var source =  fs.readFileSync(helpers + file, "utf8"),
    helperName = /(.+)\.html/.exec(file).pop();

    var helperTemplate = Handlebars.compile(source);

    // We assume all helpers in the folder
    // would take a hash as their first param
    // We'll provide them with all the required context
    Handlebars.registerHelper(helperName, function (options) {

        var hash = options.hash || {};

        // I want to somehow 'pass' the body Content ; 
        // The closest I have is 'this', but the markup is 
        // encoded, so I get a string with '<p>My body content</p>'
        hash.bodyContent = options.fn(this);

        console.log("Body Content", hash.bodyContent);

        // Render the source as an handlebar template
        // in the context of a hash
        return helperTemplate(hash);

    });
});
```

This does not work, as the tags are escaped, and so bodyContent is a String containing the markup, instead of the markup.

Is there a way I can fix my helper registration, or a built in mechanism in Handlebars to deal with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `{{{triple stashes}}}` to unescape the HTML injection. So your template should look like:

```
<p>Hello {{ who }}<p>
{{{ bodyContent }}}
<p>Bye !</p>
```

You can read more [here](http://handlebarsjs.com)